# Converting RGB to Grayscale by reference

Tags: color-correction, colorchecker

There is such a problem.

There is shooting on a color camera with a ColorChecker. And there is shooting on another, grayscale camera with the same color checker. Is it possible to somehow convert the first RGB image to the second (Grayscale) based on the ColorChecker?
I found a tutorial on how to do this in [3D Lut Creator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wEyxsFaJwe8&t), but it seems that the result is not completely accurate there.
How else can you do this?

Comment: Can we assume by "black & white" you actually mean greyscale?

Comment: Tetsujin, Yes exactly

Comment: What cameras are you using?  If digital, what processing is being done to obtain the color and grayscale images?  What do you mean by "not completely accurate"?

Comment: I am conducting an experiment as in the tutorial to which I left the link in the post. 
If you look at it, you can see that the final image in grayscale is different, which is what the author says (although it is close to the target). I would like to know what other ways there are to carry out such a conversion from RGB to grayscale.
In my case, I want to get a conversion between a Canon color DSLR camera and a Basler machine vision camera. It is important for me to get the same grayscale after converting RGB to grayscale based on the ColorChecker, which was shot from both cameras

Comment: _ I found a tutorial on how to do this in 3D Lut Creator, but it seems that the result is not completely accurate_ ... how is it not accurate? Can you provide examples of your attempts?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot show the pictures. In the tutorial itself, the author shows this inaccuracy. I'm wondering if there are other options to do this besides 3D LUT Creator?